# MYSQL How to add an auto-decrement Schedule on MySql?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, schedule

I am trying to do some automatic function on MySql.
I need that all arrows of a column named **vipdays** decrease by 1 on a daily basis.

I mean.. today the values of all arrows of the column vipdays = 30
Tomorrow all values = 29.. next day 28... and I need that this function
be automatic, that works without manually removing 1 day.

I have made some research and found some MySql Scheduler that automate
some functions but can't make it to work.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should create EVENT that is executed once a day and enable scheduler (it is disabled by default).
It should work.

However, do you really want to do this?
You can store expire date in database instead of the number (ex: "DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INVERVAL 30 DAYS)") and then compare it with CURDATE() to check if it is expired.

Comment: Thanks for our answer! And how can i make this "compare it with Curdate()", buddy?

Comment: I do not know what logic are you after. If you are after records, that are not expired yet, something "WHERE expire > CURDATE()" would do the trick. If you need expired records, you should use "WHERE expire <= CURDATE()".